# Regex: Lazy matching in nested match group

Tags: regex

I'm having problems with the following Regex:

```
I login with (CORRECT|INCORRECT (username|password|username and password)) credentials
```

Basically, what I want it to match is the following 4 strings only (which it does):

1. I login with CORRECT credentials
2. I login with INCORRECT username credentials
3. I login with INCORRECT password credentials
4. I login with INCORRECT username and password credentials

However, the match groups are as follows:

1. 1: CORRECT 2:
2. 1: INCORRECT username 2: username
3. 1: INCORRECT password 2: password
4. 1: INCORRECT username and password 2: username and password

I want the match groups as follows:

1. 1: CORRECT
2. 1: INCORRECT 2: username
3. 1: INCORRECT 2: password
4. 1: INCORRECT 2: username and password

Comment: Try `(?|` for the outer group so that it numbers subpatterns based on which option is matched.

Comment: What engine is it you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use an engine that supports `Branch Reset` it can be done like this

`I login with (?|(CORRECT)()|(INCORRECT) (username(?: and password)?|password)) credentials`

The group numbering is *reset* on each alternation in the branch reset group:

```
 I [ ] login [ ] with [ ] 
 (?|                           # Branch reset
      ( CORRECT )                   # (1)
      ( )                           # (2)
   |                              # or,
      ( INCORRECT )                 # (1)
      [ ] 
      (                             # (2 start)
           username 
           (?: [ ] and [ ] password )?
        |  
           password
      )                             # (2 end)
 )                             # End branch reset
 [ ] credentials
```

---

Or, if branch reset is unavailable use this

`I login with (?:(CORRECT)|(INCORRECT) (username|password|username and password)) credentials`

What this does is capture correct/incorrect in separate groups, then
if group 2 matched, group 3 is valid.
It still matches the exact same strings.

```
 I[ ]login[ ]with[ ]
 (?:
      ( CORRECT )                   # (1)
   |  ( INCORRECT )                 # (2)
      [ ]
      ( username | password | username[ ]and[ ]password )  # (3)
 )
 [ ]credentials
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need nested groups, you can use this regex with fixed first group and an optional 2nd group:

```
I login with ((?:IN)?CORRECT) (?:(username|password|username and password) )?credentials
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nS8eY2/1)

Comment: The problem is if the OP requires only CORRECT credentials, because that's how he set up his regex.